# Reformating existing json file

Tags: python, json

I have the next json file:

```
{ "data":  [    { "{#SQP}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid", "{#SQP_ID}": "squid1", "{#SQP_ARG}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid1.conf", "{#SQP_PT}": "1111", "{#SQP_CONFIG}": "/etc/squid1.conf" },    { "{#SQP}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid", "{#SQP_ID}": "squid2", "{#SQP_ARG}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid2.conf", "{#SQP_PT}": "2222 3333", "{#SQP_CONFIG}": "/etc/squid2.conf" },    { "{#SQP}": "/usr/local/squid/bin/squid", "{#SQP_ID}": "squid3", "{#SQP_ARG}": "-D -C -F -f /etc/squid3.conf", "{#SQP_PT}": "4444", "{#SQP_CONFIG}": "/etc/squid3.conf" }  ]}
```

This file is being read by python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import re
import sys
import unittest
import StringIO

def loadSquidPorts(discoveryJson, spJson):
    jsn = json.load(discoveryJson)
    for dt in jsn['data']:
        try:
            id = dt['{#SQP_ID}']
            port = dt['{#SQP_PT}']
            spJson['data'].append({'{ID}': id, '{#PORT}': port})
        except Exception as err:
            pass

def printSquidPortDiscovery(discFilespec, dumpDest=sys.stdout):
    portJson = {'data': []}
    try:
        with open(discFilespec) as discJson:
            loadSquidPorts(discJson, portJson)
    except:
        pass
    json.dump(portJson, dumpDest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printSquidPortDiscovery('/root/file.json')
```

The output of python script is th next:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "{#ID}": "squid1",
                "{#PORT}": "1111"
            },
            {
                "{#ID}": "squid2",
                "{#PORT}": "2222 3333"
            },
            {
                "{#ID}": "squid3",
                "{#PORT}": "4444"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need that this python script in case of several port values - print them separately, eg:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "{#ID}": "squid1",
                "{#PORT}": "1111"
            },
            {
                "{#ID}": "squid2",
                "{#PORT}": "2222",
                "{#PORT}": "3333"
            },
            {
                "{#ID}": "squid3",
                "{#PORT}": "4444"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Already edited.

Comment: There is no way you can do that, because you need to have unique keys.

Comment: Why do you want to do it? It can be done afterwards if you will. But what is the point in doing so? Without pre processing you won't be able to convert it to json afterwards.

Comment: for port `values` it should be ideally a list as the value for "{#PORT}"

Comment: I need it for lowlevel discovery in Zabbix. If I'll use a list of ports - metrics only for one of ports will be gathered. So I need somehow to separate ports in order they be added separately to items: 2222 for item1 etc instead of 2222 3333 to one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
spJson['data'].append({'{ID}': id, '{#PORT}': port})
```

Use:

```
port_data = dict()
port_data['{#ID}'] = id
port_data['{#PORTS}'] = port.split(" ")
spJson['data'].append(port_data)
```

That will give you port IDs as a list:

```
{
  "{#ID}": "squid1",
  "{#PORTS}": [
    "555",
    "777"
  ]
}
```

If you don't want a list, try keys with numbered suffixes:

```
port_data = dict()
port_data['{#ID}'] = id
i=0
for single_port in port.split(" "):
 port_data["{#PORT-" + str(i) + "}"] = single_port
 i=i+1
spJson['data'].append(port_data)
```

The output in this case:

```
{
  "{#ID}": "squid6",
  "{#PORT-0}": "555",
  "{#PORT-1}": "777"
}
```